# Quick fix for parallel use of a non thread safe library

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, appdomain

I'm using a library that isn't thread safe but doesn't use other non thread safe external ressources.

It's a bit of a pain to make it thread safe (main reason it's not thread safe is that it uses a lot of static fields that it reads/writes to on a per instance basis, works just fine with many instances processed sequentially buy obviously fails if using multiple instances in parallel)

I'm thinking of doing the following as a quick fix that feels hackish and i'm wondering if there is anything inherently wrong with this approach.

Create an app domain per thread, marshall the thread data to that domain, load the library in each domain and run as many app domains as i have threads, then unload when done.

I understand this implies a slowdown (many library loads and lots of marshalling back and force) but that aside am i missing something obvious that makes this impossible?

Comment: Sounds feasible to me if you can live with the cost of spinning up the app domains. Would be interesting to see if you find this beneficial overall.

Comment: @Biscuits The cost of each sequential call today is substantial (not "long" in human terms but still huge in low level terms, depending on the input anywhere between 5 seconds to 1 minute). On the other hand the amount of data to transfer to/from the the library is small (in the order of a few KB) so i'm pretty confident the cost of creating / deleting appdomains and marshalling data will be lower than the gain of having to do those sequentially on the target hardware by a high amount. Just trying to make sure i'm not taking a silly road as i've never seen that solution suggested before

Comment: What you're trying to do is scale out. This is not uncommon at all. IIS does this when you bump up worker processes on your app pool. The important thing to realise is that you'll need some form of IPC that might come at an additional cost to invoking the library in-process, and a smart way to limit how many would be beneficial to have and reuse them as much as possible in a pool. There's actually a lot you can learn from web servers to formulate your strategy.

Comment: Heck, you could implement it as a Web Service/API and let the web server do the hard work of managing the app domains.

Comment: Understanding that the only thing being invoked is this library (it's not just part of the process) then using appdomains seems like a good start.

Comment: What does the library do, if I may ask?

Comment: @Biscuits 2d poly triangulation

Comment: Are you aiming to calculate many polygons in parallel and/or parts of one polygon in parallel?

Comment: @Biscuits many polygons, but i'm done and it's working fine

Comment: Awesome! You should post an answer with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

How much of the library do you need to interact with? If it's not too huge you could build a wrapper around it. You call the wrapper's methods and it handles locking and makes thread safe calls to the inner library.

You can declare an interface, and the implementation is your wrapper class. Now in addition to solving the thread safety issue you've removed an untestable direct dependency on static methods.

It might be a little bit of work (if it's feasible, depending on the library) but it would definitely be a lot cleaner than creating app domains just to keep separate "instances" of static members.

```
// Class with static memebers
public class FooManager
{
    public static void ManageFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        // Does some non thread-safe stuff
    }
}

public interface IFooManager
{
    void ManageFoo(Foo foo);
}

public class FooManagerWrapper : IFooManager
{
    private static readonly object FooManagerLock = new object();

    public void ManageFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        lock (FooManagerLock)
        {
            FooManager.ManageFoo(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

[This blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/25/adapter-pattern.html) contains another example. Even if thread safety isn't an issue I don't want my code to have a direct dependency on static classes and methods (even if I wrote them.)

Comment: But this removes any benefit to parallelizing it if i'm locking on it, it will end up being N threads working 1 at a time instead of N threads working N at a time. What i want is the performance gain of multithreading without working on fixing the whole library.

Comment: It depends - if the only thing your parallel operation is doing is using this library then it's not going to be very beneficial. But if there are other operations going on then there will be some benefit.

Comment: there aren't, this step is basically hundreds of calls to this library which i'm currently forced to do sequentially. The code is basically a foreach with 1 call to the library that i want to turn into a parallel.foreach. There is strictly nothig i can do functionally before all of the calls to the library are done (need the all of return values of all items for the next step)